# Unable to copy file "source" to "target". Access to the path "target" is denied

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, tfs, compilation, dependencies

I know that this is a common error and have read dozens of threads on dozens of sites today trying to fix the issue.

I branched a project in TFS and got latest on it.  When I opened the project, the branched version will not compile due to the "Unable to Copy" exception on two project references.  The solution consists of several projects that include some dependencies on each other.

- ActiveDirectories has no project dependencies
- DataModel has no project dependencies
- DataAccess is dependent on DataModel
- BL is depenedent on ActiveDirectories, DataAccess, and DataModel
- SmartClient is dependent on ActiveDirectories, BL, and DataModel

When I compile, I get 9 errors stating that the dll, xml, and pdb files for ActiveDirectories, DataModel, and DataAccess cannot be copied to the bin\debug folder.

I have tried many solutions including the following:

- Cleaning the solution
- Deleting the entire bin folder
- Ensuring that all of these references are set to Copy Local
- Shutting down VS completely and restarting
- Deleting the entire folder and getting latest from TFS
- Setting the read only attribute to false on the BIN folder and all subfolders
- Ensuring that the bin folder was not checked into TFS

If anyone has any ideas, I would be so grateful.

Thanks,
Lance

Comment: can you post the actual error?  are the references pointing to the other branch?

Answer (score 0):

This was a simple folly on my part.  I was thinking that the error was occurring in the SmartClient project when it was in fact happening in the BL project.